# Get a single data using PDO and store in a variable

Tags: php, pdo, display

I have this php script to update data. I need to store result from a query using SUM. I have the code below.

```
$query=$DBcon->prepare("SELECT SUM(fee) FROM users WHERE list_no=:list_no");
$query->bindParam(':list_no', $sp_no);
$query->execute();
$result = $query -> fetch();
echo $result["figure"];
```

It displays ARRAY...

Comment: Try `"SELECT SUM(fee) \`figure\` FROM users WHERE list_no=:list_no"`. I am a bit confused though because it shouldn't display array

Comment: `echo $result["SUM(fee)"];`

Comment: Got it! thank you guys...

Comment: I'm confused how `echo $result["figure"]` could possibly display anything but a notice about an undefined index... given the SQL shown in the code above contains no field of `figure`.

Answer (score 1):

If your selecting a single column you can do this:

```
$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
echo $result;
```

Comment: that's instead of
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query -> fetch();

Answer (score 0):

The shortest solution is:

```
echo $query->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: LUL that's not true

Comment: @bassxzero why not? Do you have a shorter solution?

Comment: yeah I posted it as a comment to OP's question

Answer (score 0):

I think changing echo to `print_r($result);` will give you the answer. You can also try `var_dump` on each variable to debug the issues